# Looping dict[key] into gui interface, removing, and replacing

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

So I have this code for Python 2.7 which calculates word frequencies (any optimizations are welcome).

```
import Tkinter as tk

def let_freq():
    user_input = e.get()
    alphabet = {
        'a': 0,'b': 1,'c': 2,'d': 3,
        'e': 4,'f': 5,'g': 6,'h': 7,
        'i': 8,'j': 9,'k': 10,'l': 11,
        'm': 12,'n': 13,'o': 14,'p': 15,
        'q': 16,'r': 17,'s': 18,'t': 19,
        'u': 20,'v': 21,'w': 22,'x': 23,'y': 2,'z': 25}

    value_alphabet = {
        'a': 0,'b': 0,'c': 0,'d': 0,
        'e': 0,'f': 0,'g': 0,'h': 0,
        'i': 0,'j': 0,'k': 0,'l': 0,
        'm': 0,'n': 0,'o': 0,'p': 0,
        'q': 0,'r': 0,'s': 0,'t': 0,
        'u': 0,'v': 0,'w': 0,'x': 0,'y': 0,'z': 0}

    letters = []
    count = 0
    for character in user_input:
        letters.append(character)

    for item in letters:
        for key, val in alphabet.items():
            if key is item:
                value_alphabet[key] += 1

    for key in value_alphabet:
        if value_alphabet[key] > 0:
            count += value_alphabet[key]

    for key in sorted(value_alphabet):
        if value_alphabet[key] > 0:
            print value_alphabet[key], ',', key, '-', float(value_alphabet[key])/count*100, '%'


root = tk.Tk()
e = tk.Entry(root)
assert type(e)
e.grid(ipadx=5,ipady=5)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Letterfrequency',command=let_freq).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Now, the problem is displaying the

```
print value_alphabet[key], ',', key, '-', float(value_alphabet[key])/count*100, '%'
```

in a Tkinter Label or any other appropriate Tkinter widget and I'd like to know how to actively edit a Label within the loop, remove them if the `user_input` variable changes, and (this should come naturally) display the information of the new entry in `user_input` (`e` prior to the '`e.get()`' section).

(i.e. if you input 'banana', you should get a-50%, n-33.333333333%, b-16.666666666%...it is word frequency)

Answer (score 1):

When setting up a Label, you can give it a `tkinter.StringVar` as it's text variable. Then, whenever you update the variable, the Label will update automatically:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

root = Tk()
labeltext = StringVar()
labeltext.set('hello')

label = Label(root, textvariable = labeltext)
label.pack()

for i in range(10):
    labeltext.set(str(i))
    root.update_idletasks()
    sleep(1) #slow it down so that the changes are visible
```

This code will update the label inside the for loop. Now, you just need to `labeltext.set(str(user_input))` and you will get the user input on the label.

Comment: `StringVar` also takes a kwarg `value` that gives it a default text value. `StringVar(value='foobar')`

Answer (score 1):

A few tweaks on your function before getting to the question at hand. You're doing a bunch of stuff you don't really need to, and can pare this down quite a bit.

First of all, your `value_alphabet` is just a reimplemented `collections.Counter`. Use that instead.

```
from collections import Counter

...

    value_alphabet = Counter()
```

You're also doing some funky low-level stuff that A) isn't necessary in Python and B) isn't the best way to do that in Python even if it were necessary. I'm talking about

```
letters = []

for character in user_input:
    letters.append(character)
```

This is just

```
letters = list(user_input)
```

But since you can iterate directly over a string, you don't need `letters` AT ALL. Remove it. Similarly `count` is just `len(user_input)`. All you do is loop over each letter and count them up. Toss it. Now your function looks like:

```
def let_freq():
    user_input = e.get()
    alphabet = {
        'a': 0,'b': 1,'c': 2,'d': 3,
        'e': 4,'f': 5,'g': 6,'h': 7,
        'i': 8,'j': 9,'k': 10,'l': 11,
        'm': 12,'n': 13,'o': 14,'p': 15,
        'q': 16,'r': 17,'s': 18,'t': 19,
        'u': 20,'v': 21,'w': 22,'x': 23,'y': 2,'z': 25}
    value_alphabet = Counter()

    for item in user_input:
        for key,val in alphabet.items():
            if key is item:
                value_alphabet[key] += 1
```

That loop there is pretty ugly. You're neglecting the best part of dictionaries: O(1) lookups! You don't need to do the double loop. `if key is item` is bad for other reasons, but I won't go into that here since identity vs equality isn't really in the same kettle of fish as this (and it doesn't affect functionality here. Just know that 'somestring is somestring' isn't always `True`.)

```
   for ch in user_input:  # changed the loopvar here to sound better
       value_alphabet[ch] += alphabet[ch]
       # look it up directly.
```

If you're worried about the user_input including invalid characters, use `dict.get` instead to default to zero.

```
   for ch in user_input:
       value_alphabet += alphabet.get(ch, 0)
       # if ch isn't in alphabet, do value_alphabet += 0
```

Sweet! We're almost sorted now. Let's move on. Since we've done away with your `count` variable, we can skip the next `for key in value_alphabet` loop since it only populates `count`. For your last bit, you can shorten your code by doing:

```
for key,val in sorted(value_alphabet.items()):
    if val > 0:
        print val, ',', key, '-', float(val * 100 / len(user_input)), '%'
```

---

Now for your question about changing a label? You're looking for callbacks. You should probably roll this into its own class rather than just have it hanging out in the middle of nowhere, but let's talk about binding a callback to the user entry changing. The easiest way to do this is using `tk.StringVar` and its `trace` method.

```
root = tk.Tk()
e_stringvar = tk.StringVar()
e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=e_stringvar)
e_stringvar.trace('w', some_func)
```

This binds `e_stringvar` together with your `tk.Entry` widget, storing the contents of `e` in `e_stringvar`. Furthermore it binds some unknown function `some_func` to `e_stringvar` so that every time `e_stringvar` has something written to it (e.g. `e` has changed due to user entry), it calls `some_func`. We could define `some_func` as something like:

```
f = tk.Label(root)
f.pack()
e.pack()   # whatever, pack everything

def some_func(*args, **kwargs):
    text = e_stringvar.get()
    f.configure(text=text)
    # change the f label so it's displaying the same text as the entry
```

I've defined `some_func` to take arguments, because I honestly forget if the `tk.StringVar.trace` callback functions get passed the event that triggered them. We're not using them, but if you don't allow it to be passed you'll get ArgumentErrors.

---

I've written a bit of (Py3) code somewhat recently that uses this concept to track a `tk.Entry` field and use it to filter a text list. The relevant code is on bitbucket [findppw.views.frames](https://bitbucket.org/darimart/find-paperwork/src/3e03b8982152c557b3ae6c92368e60b3bd935092/views/frames.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) (the FilterFrame class) and [findppw.app](https://bitbucket.org/darimart/find-paperwork/src/3e03b8982152c557b3ae6c92368e60b3bd935092/app.pyw?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) (line 38 instantiates FilterFrame and names its callback func)

Comment: With `value_alphabet = Counter()` how would                                         `for ch in user_input:
       value_alphabet += alphabet[ch]` exactly work because it throws me a type error when it encounters the `+=` section: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Counter' and 'int'`

Comment: `collections.Counter` objects are special objects that are very good at storing `<object> -> int` mappings. It's literally what they're made to do. I did make a typo (should be `value_alphabet[ch] += ...`) but you're storing the score of that letter.

Comment: With that fix `value_alphabet[ch] += alphabet[ch]` it'll run the code with exit code 0; However, if you input 'banana' it says that there are 26 'n', 1 'b', and doesn't even list 'a'.

Comment: @komoka pay attention to what's being counted. Hint: it's not the letter frequency.

Comment: If you just want letter frequency, `Counter(user_input)` does that for you. No looping needed. I assumed `alphabet` was a Scrabble-scoring kind of mapping. Perhaps I'm wrong and it's not needed at all!

Comment: Well, with no list to keep track of which values have been found, I can use `for ch in user_input: print value_alphabet[ch], '-', ch` to find that it's just repeating 'n' and 'a', and without a list how would you keep track of what not to find again (i.e. instead of 1-b, 3-a, 2-n, 3-a, 2-n, 3-a have it produce 1-b, 3-a, 2-n and be done)

Comment: I suppose I'm not sure what output you're looking for, because what you just said made no sense. You definitely don't need either the `alphabet` dict or the `letters` list, no matter WHAT you're doing, but without knowing what kind of output you're trying to get, it's tough to say what code is going to produce it :P

Comment: edited question. I'm looking for word frequency, number of occurrences / total number of letters

Comment: @komoka note however that dictionaries (like the `collections.Counter` object which is just a special kind of dictionary) cannot contain duplicates. `Counter("banana")` will give you `Counter({"a": 3, "n": 2, "b": 1})`